# Dynamic Naming Of Columns In SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

This may be a duplicate question, but I have looked elsewhere and have ended up being confused by the information provided. I am not very experienced in SQL.

Essentially, I have a table `course_scores` which has a column for each question and a row for each person completing the form. Currently, the columns are labelled `q1_ans`, `q2_ans` etc. and the data for the questions answers are numeric (`int`)

I also have a `feedback_questions` table which has three columns, `question` which contains the values `q1_ans`, `q2_ans` etc., `text` which contains the text of the questions, and `question_type` which contains the question type.

I need to produce views which contain the column names dependent on the text strings in the `feedback_questions` table. If I update the `feedback_questions` table, the columns need to update. If it is also possible, I would also like to group the columns by the question types in the `feedback_questions` table.

My current research suggests I need to use a dynamic SQL query, but I don't have any experience of using this and have been confused by other similar questions.

Comment: that's a bad table design. no matter how many `q` columns you think you'll need, there'll ALWAYS be a requirement for `n+1`. [Normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your design, and then this problem goes away entirely... you'll be able to support 0->infinity "columns", aka questions.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I know what you mean. Should I have a `question_number` column and an `answer` column? If so, how do I account for a change of data type across the questions?